# Kotlin Android App Use Default Device Theme(s)

Tags: android, kotlin, themes

I created a new Android app in Android Studio and selected a simple project template and Kotlin as the language. The app that's generated has a purple toolbar and purple buttons. I know where those colors are defined (in the different color definitions in the project's `themes.xml` file) but I want the app to just use the default themes (light and dark) currently defined on the device.

How do I disconnect the custom theme and just let the app use the defaults for the device. My device's running Android 12, so the current theme could be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Your applcation theme should inherit from DynamicColors like this:

values/themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.Light">

</style>
```

Dark theme:
values-night/themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DynamicColors.Dark">

</style>
```

Do not define colors like for example "colorPrimary" or "colorSurface" inside your Theme.App style.

Reference the created theme in your Manifest:

```
 <application
    ....
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App">
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, I don't want to have any custom colors or theme defined. My question is about how do I ONLY use the device themes in my app.

Comment: Do not define custom colors. This theme uses the colors of your wallpaper on Android 12

Comment: so do what? delete the styles.xml file? Delete the color definitions somewhere?  I'm trying to understand what to do to fix this

Comment: I edited the answer so it is more straight forward what to do. You can leave your styles.xml as is. In general App themes should be defined in values/themes.xml and custom styles (e.g. a custom button style) should be defined in values/styles.xml.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but can't make it work. I'll dig into this more tomorrow.